# GitHub Copilot Chat: Responses don't appear in Github Copilot Chat window in Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: visual-studio-2022, github-copilot

I'm currently using Visual Studio 2022 Community Edition along with a paid plan for GitHub Copilot. I've managed to successfully install the Copilot extension and have been experimenting with the "Ask Copilot" feature.

When I use "Ask Copilot," the input box appears right within the code window, and I can see the response directly in the same code window. However, I've noticed that this approach doesn't retain the chat history.

In various tutorials, I've seen developers asking questions directly in the code window while the responses are redirected to the GitHub Copilot Chat window. This seems to come with the added benefit of having a chat history.

My question is: Is there a specific setting that I'm missing or a different approach to achieve this split between asking questions in the code window and receiving responses in the GitHub Copilot Chat window? Or was this behaviour perhaps part of an earlier implementation that has since changed?

I appreciate any insights or guidance on how to make the most out of the GitHub Copilot integration in Visual Studio 2022.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: Unfortunately not.